# Is Abstract Algebra effectively Pre-Calc Algebra but more "abstract"?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have taken up to Pre-Calc/Algebra, and being made to plug and chug in a ready-made formula to arrive at an answer is boring.

*I would really love to delve into the "why's" behind why certain formulas and algebraic techniques (such as completing the square or matrices/Kramer's rule) work in certain scenarios and why they break down in others.*

***Is this what Abstract Algebra is all about? Answering the "why" behind why we do certain operations/computations in PreCalc-Algebra?***

I want to get creative with my own intuitive approach towards solving problems and not rely on regurgitation of formulas I don't fully understand from where they came.

Comment: There's a lot more to it than that.

Comment: A good pre-calculus class should itself explain "why" you do certain operations, clearly enough that you can convince yourself the operations are valid and correct without having to trust the authority of the book or the teacher. No advanced math is required to understand high school algebra and pre-calc deeply.  However, undergrad analysis courses typically develop the real number system axiomatically and prove everything in calculus from the axioms.  That is something you might be interested in learning about.  The textbook Calculus by Spivak might be worth checking out.

Comment: It's generally a good idea to simply separate them. They use the same word. There's a relationship, but it is tenuous and not likely to give you a good impression of what the topic is.

Comment: Comparing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_algebra with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_algebra would suggest not only are they at different levels but also that they are talking about different things.  I would say that high-school algebra leads naturally towards calculus, analysis and linear algebra (i.e. useful things) but not towards abstract algebra (weird and deep structures)

Comment: I suggest that the course you seem to be describing would be more "rigorous" than that you have apparently already had.  But you have not described a course in abstract algebra.  Abstract (or modern) algebra is quite different than a precalculus course.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question is way too vague to have a useful answer on MSE. "PreCalc Algebra" and "Abstract Algebra" aren't specific topics in mathematics.I am sure there are other fora that are more appropriate for your question.

Comment: Abstract algebra has a lot of generalization. You study things like rings and groups; things that may or may not share some general properties in common with, say, the integers. If we have a thing, like a set with a binary operation or two, that satisfies certain properties, what else can we say about it?

Comment: What is PreCalc-Algebra? Is it stuff like $\frac{x^2-y^2}{x+y} = x-y$?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments! @littleO The pre-calculus textbooks do explain why certain manipulations are done but only after showing us the algorithm at first, but it doesn't really teach us how to come up with them on our own. Which is the type of course I am really looking for.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews
Ah. Okay. I really think the usage of the same word is what's throwing me off. To go from "College Algebra" and then hear about "Modern Algebra" registers in the brain as just a more "updated" version of the same studied in high school. Even abstraction is taught in highschool so a lot of the attempts to explain the differences online just aren't very helpful.

Comment: @Henry
This is really interesting. If this is true I'll definitely be taking up Real Analysis instead. I once saw my professor use a variety of trig identities to solve a problem the books had never shown before. It was quite creative and since then I have wanted to learn to be able to creatively solve problems without such reliance on handed down formulas that I'm told to trust and believe in.

Comment: @Ennar. Yes. Just like that.

Comment: @JimH so would you say Real analysis would be the way forward like some of the other posters suggest? Thanks!

Comment: @user252810 I'd be curious to hear an example of something where the precalculus book doesn't explain how to come up with it on your own.  (I do agree that math books often fail to explain how you could have thought of certain ideas yourself. A lot of times I find more enlightening explanations on this forum.)

Comment: @littleO the most recent one I've run into is my Statistics 1 class with the standard deviation formula. It makes sense that you would want the numerator to be composed of all positive numbers since we are trying to find the distance of the individual sample means from the population mean but why not take the absolute value instead of squaring each one though? And why divided over "n-1"? These errors I would have made coming up with them on my own the books don't explain why. There are many more especially from Calculus 1-2 but I can't think of them at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think "answering the why's" is the key difference. Mostly, in abstract algebra you'll be dealing with two things not present in PreCalc Algebra: proofs and argumentation. A problem in PreCalc may be: "say if **X** satisfies this property" or "Find the **Y** of this **Z**". On the other hand, Abstract Algebra will come along and say: "Suppose **B**. Prove that **N** is then **M**", and that might not be a trivial thing to even think about.

Personally, when I took Abstract Algebra I felt the main difference was learning to understand and construct mathematical (rigorous) arguments, rather than memorizing results and applying on a need-to-know basis. It won't be plug-and-chug, and it won't be "This is why that is so". It'll be "Show rigorously that you can go from **A** to **B**" (which, if you have the imagination to interpret results, is a fantastic way of learning).

Read theorems and understand them. Then when you think you have them in your pocket, read them again. Know what you can and can't do, what can and can't happen, and you'll see just how beautiful (and kind of black-magic easy) Abstract Algebra can be.

Comment: We saw some proofs in PreCalculus/Elementary Algebra too though. Like the Squeeze Theorem, Rolle's Theorem/Mean Value Theorem, etc. It just never taught us how to come up with the manipulation of symbols on our own. Such as "completing the square". The algorithm is simply taught, with little to no explanation about where it comes from, what it means or how to derive it on our own without reliance on memory. I was hoping Abstract Algebra would be able to break this all down, but maybe Real analysis does a better job of this?

Comment: It seems to me you're mixing up the concept of "deducing". In higher mathematics, when you "deduce" some result or property, you're not reinventing the wheel, from scratch, because "reliance in memory" is somehow prohibited or frowned upon. You're constantly using results and arguments (theorems) to prove further properties of whatever it is that you're studying. It's simply that, at the lower levels of education, this results become a "obvious background", so to speak, that is taken for granted. Have you ever stopped to think about what **is** a real number? :)

Answer (score 0):

Not relying on regurgitation of formulas you don't understand is what **mathematics** is all about. What you're maybe concerned about is inductive vs. deductive reasoning, where instead of getting a formula and a set of problems for the formula to help you realize that the formula really works (which would be an example of an inductive conclusion, aka "it really works for these 1000 examples, it must work for all examples"), you want to arrive at a conclusion from a set of hypotheses based on certain logical rules (which is deductive reasoning).

Inductive reasoning is used in early mathematical education, as deduction and proofs etc. are too abstract for young kids and early teens. As you progress through your education, (depending on where you're from, either in later high school or university) your courses should start being more deductive in their nature. A great example of this is Euclidean geometry - the ancient Greeks were one of the first civilizations to achieve a somewhat formal treatment of a mathematical subject, and learning from their approach in establishing geometry is often a great starting point for one's deductive "career"!

To answer your question about abstract algebra, let's say very crudely that it studies ordered $(n+1)$-tuples of the form $(S, \cdot_{1}, ..., \cdot_{n})$, where $S$ is a set, and $\cdot_{k}, 1 \leq k \leq n$ are operations, i.e. mappings from $S^{i_{k}}$ to $S$, where $i_{k}$ would be the **length** of the operation (the number of arguments the operation takes - for example, $+$ and $\cdot$, addition and multiplication of natural numbers, are **binary** operations - they take two arguments). Obviously, abstract algebra also studies many, many more things; drawing boundaries between areas of mathematics has always been difficult, and is especially difficult today. The difference between abstract algebra and algebra taught in early high school would almost definitely be the approach - abstract algebra takes a strict mathematical approach, and all reasoning done is deductive (although inductive reasoning is an *extremely* useful mathematical skill, as you can often get abstract ideas by looking at concrete examples - examples inspire **questions** and **curiosity**, which are two of some of the most important things in mathematics).

Comment: So according to your first two paragraphs, I should eventually encounter a subject that will teach me how to arrive at a conclusion deductively as long as I keep progressing up mathematics? Awesome! 

I was just curious as to whether or not this would be more in the subject of Abstract Algebra or Real Analysis?